# Как увидеть разницу между stateless и stateful session-бинами в EJB?

Tags: java, java-ee

По идее, stateless бин не должен сохранять своё состояние (значения своих полей) после завершения запроса. Например, вызов метода GetSum(13) каждый раз должен возвращать "13".

```
import javax.ejb.*;  
import javax.jws.*;

@Stateless  
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ITestWebService")   
public class TestWebService implements ITestWebService  
{  
    private double sum = 0.0;

    @Override 
    public double GetSum( double a )
    {
        this.sum += a;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Но повторный вызов возвращает 13, 26, 39, ... Я неправильно понимаю stateless или можно грешить на сервер приложений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stateless означает, что бин не держит состояние между сессиями. То есть надо "убить" бин чтобы увидеть что он не сохраняет свое внутреннее состояние.

Comment: Как я понял, пока сессия не перезапустится, разницы между stateless и stateful не видно, а stateful - обладает некими персистентными свойствами. Так получается? В любом случае спасибо за ответ (:

Comment: Представьте, что после каждого обращения к бину его значение записывается в БД, так что даже после убийства бина его значение остается записанным - это будет stateful, stateless - значение сохраняется только пока бин жив.

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение!

Answer (score 0):

У `Stateful` бина есть события `@PrePassivate` и `@PostActivate` для сериализации. Т.е. при нехватке ОЗУ этот бин может сохраняться на жесткий диск.